# A simple complex query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I write a simple complex query in mysql:

```
SELECT bcode, MAX(c)
from (SELECT bcode, COUNT(*) as c 
  FROM register 
  GROUP BY bcode)
```

but I have following error, why?

1.An expression was expected. (near "(" at position 27)

2.Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 27)

3.This type of clause was previously parsed. (near "SELECT" at position 28)

4.Unexpected closing bracket. (near ")" at position 100)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All subqueries in the `FROM` clause require an alias in MySQL:

```
SELECT bcode, MAX(c)
FROM (SELECT bcode, COUNT(*) as c 
      FROM register 
      GROUP BY bcode
     ) c;
```

Note:  The above query returns an indeterminate value of `bcode` along with the maximum count.  It is using a (mis)feature of MySQL that allows columns in the `SELECT` that are not aggregated, in an aggregation query.  (I could note that SQLite recognizes the above syntax and does what you want, but that is just an abomination -- in my opinion.)

I doubt this is what you want.  You probably intend:

```
SELECT bcode, COUNT(*) as c 
FROM register 
GROUP BY bcode
ORDER BY c DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

If you want all `bcodes` with the maximum value, I think  I would recommend

```
SELECT c, GROUP_CONCAT(bcode)
FROM (SELECT bcode, COUNT(*) as c 
      FROM register 
      GROUP BY bcode
     ) c
ORDER BY c DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

This puts them all on one row in a comma-delimited list.  There are other methods, but I think that is the simplest in MySQL (almost every other database supports `rank()` which makes this much simpler).